# How to get rid of org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar?

Tags: eclipse, junit, classpath

I have a project with unit tests. I'm using Maven and m2e. With Maven from the command line, I see:

```
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- junit:junit-dep:jar:4.10:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.9.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.2.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.0:test
```

`mvn install` works, all the tests run. Good.

Now I try to run the unit tests from within Eclipse using m2e 1.2.0 and I get this error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.hamcrest.DiagnosingMatcher"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:806)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:487)
        ...
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

which puzzles me. The dependency tree in m2e looks good. But when I open the properties of the process, I get a modified classpath which contains these additional entries:

```
.../eclipse/3.7.2/eclipse/plugins/org.junit_4.8.2.v4_8_2_v20110321-1705/junit.jar
.../eclipse/plugins/org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar
```

Since these JARs are signed, the tests fail. How can I get rid of these two entries? Or how can I make sure they are added late in the classpath (i.e. after my version of JUnit + Hamcrest)?

Answer (score 4):

I found a workaround.

The reason for the error is that Eclipse's JUnit launcher adds the JUnit and Hamcrest bundle to the classpath. These two are signed Orbit bundles while the JARs from Maven are not signed.

Hamcrest 1.2 contains more classes than Eclipse's Hamcrest 1.1. If Hamcrest 1.1 is loaded first, Java will expect all classes in the package `org.hamcrest` to share the same cryptographic signatures. This isn't true and there is no way to fix that.

The error goes away when I manually add a dependency via "Java Build Path" or in the "Classpath" tab of the launch configuration.

In these places, I can make sure that the JARs from `.m2/repository/` appear first in the classpath (before the JDT JUnit runner adds the JARs from Eclipse's plugins folder) so Java will never see / try to load the bundles from Orbit.

In the launch configuration, it looks like this:

[image: Launch Configuration]

But I'd prefer if Eclipse didn't mess with my classpath :-(

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two possibilities:

1. You've got junit on the classpath already. In Project Properties->Java Build Path, Libraries tab, do you have multiple junit libraries on the path, that is have you added the junit library to the project. If so, remove it and try again.
2. The more likely cause is your usage of hamcrest 1.2. This is not compatible with JUnit 4.10 (or 4.8 for that matter). JUnit pre-4.11 included some of the hamcrest 1.1 classes, so you can get incompatibility problems. Your best bet is to upgrade to 4.11, which doesn't include the hamcrest libraries, but has hamcrest 1.3 as a transitive dependency. If you can use hamcrest 1.3 do that, if not, 1.2 *should* work.

Comment: 1. Junit is not on the Java Build Path. 2. I'm using `junit-dep` which doesn't include any Hamcrest classes. The problem is that the jdt Junit launcher seems to add JUnit and Hamcrest to the classpath (and old versions, too) but I'm not sure how to prevent this.